# Problems with Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell

I have a problems with `Get-AdUser` cmdlet. In fact, if I run my program using the scheduled task, `Get-AdUser` returns the following message:

```
Impossible de contacter le serveur.
Il se peut que le serveur n’existe pas, est actuellement hors service ou ne dispose pas des services Web Active Directory.
```

On the other hand, when I run my program directly in PowerShell , the program works and `Get-Aduser` does not return errors.

```
$ADUsers = Get-ADUser -Server "server.place.com" -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=ad,DC=activedirectory,DC=com" -Properties Department, Description, DisplayName, EmailAddress, EmployeeID, Office, OfficePhone, Title, SamAccountName
```

Note: I use PSVersion 7.3.4

Comment: What user is running the scheduled task??

Comment: FYI, translation of the error into English is :
"Unable to contact the server.
The server may not exist, is currently down, or does not have Active Directory Web Services."